# forward declarations, and template instantiation context

Tags: c++, templates

I have a header that forward declares a struct, a function, and defines a template function that uses the struct concrete type:

---header.h

```
struct RegisterImpl;
RegisterImpl& getRegisterImpl();

template <typename Interface>
void registerModuleClass( .... )
{
  RegisterImpl& reg = getRegisterImpl();
  reg.data = 3;
  ...
}
```

---source.cpp

```
struct RegisterImpl
{
  int data;
};

RegisterImpl& getRegisterImpl()
{
  static RegisterImpl instance;
  return instance;
}

struct testiFace
{
   virtual void Blah() = 0;
};

void useTemplate()
{
   registerModuleClass<testiFace>(....);
}
```

my hope was that instantiation of template function `registerModuleClass` was going to happen at `useTemplate`, which happens after the `RegisterImpl` type is fully defined. But it seems that type resolution of the code is happening at the place where the template definition exists, instead of the instantiation (at the source file)

Am i missing something here? The dilemma here is that the template function needs to use the concrete type of the implementation, but the concrete type happens in the source file. Any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this suggestion will help in your situation, but here is an idea: you could wrap the code in a class template that requires `RegisterImpl` as a template parameter.

Example:

```
template<typename T>
struct Helper
{
    T & getRegisterImpl()
    {
        static T instance;
        return instance;
    }

    template<typename Interface>
    void registerModuleClass()
    {
        T & reg = getRegisterImpl();
    }
};
```

And later:

```
struct RegisterImpl
{
    int data;
};

Helper<RegisterImpl> helper;
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make it depend on the template parameter(s):

```
template<typename T, typename...> struct depend { typedef T type; };

template <typename Interface>
void registerModuleClass( .... )
{
  typedef typename depend<RegisterImpl,Interface>::type LocalRegisterImpl;
  LocalRegisterImpl& reg = getRegisterImpl();
  reg.data = 3;
  ...
}
```